# R rmarkdown ioslides - How to include a "thank you" slide?

Tags: css, r-markdown, ioslides

How do I initiate a "thank you" slide in rmarkdown ioslides?

I've gone through the `default.css` (ioslides [version 13.5.1](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/ioslides/ioslides-13.5.1/theme/css/default.css)) and I saw that there are default `.thank-you-slide` classes.

Take this example

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Mr X"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Thank you slide

...this should have the "thank you" theme.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you do it in the Slide title:

```
## Thank you slide {.thank-you-slide}
```